# Android API 23 - HttpClient 4.X repackaged

Tags: java, android, httpclient, apache-httpclient-4.x

Disclaimer

- I know we shouldn't use HttpClient on Android anymore
- In API 23 we have option to use `useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'`

I'd like to continue using HttpClient (also I maintain libraries and projects based on it) however, with API 23 the classes are gone.

Well not gone with `useLibrary` workaround, but cannot be used to develop any further (classes don't autocomplete, everything is shown as invalid code)

We also have option to use HttpComponents provided Android fork of **HttpClient 4.3.5.1**, which however doesn't provide classes/headers/interfaces that Android provided on API < 22, so it compiles, but we're still unable to developer effectively.

Is there any full HttpClient library repackage (favorably even versions higher than 4.3) which can be used further with target/compile-Sdk of version 23 ?

Latest full repackage I could find is https://code.google.com/p/httpclientandroidlib/ which uses version 4.3.2

I've also added comment to HC JIRA issue https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HTTPCLIENT-1632

This workaround will be probably needed only until HttpClient 5.X will be released, as it should have completely different package names.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, to answer my own question, I've put up project, which will repackage and build HttpClient in bundle with HttpMime, HttpCore and HttpClient-Cache packages into different namespace.

Currently the version provided is **4.3.3** (in sync with ASF HC 4.3.3 version)

https://github.com/smarek/httpclient-android

It's quite customizable, so changing the package/artifact name or version, adjusting the build to your needs and so on should be no problem.

It's also published on Maven Central under identifier `cz.msebera.android:httpclient:4.3.3` and all your code imports currently using `org.apache.http` should be migrated (for sake of using this library) to `cz.msebera.android.httpclient`