# Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.apache.http.util.Args

Tags: java, android, noclassdeffounderror

```
  conn.addRequestProperty(entity.getContentType().getName(), entity.getContentType().getValue());
```

It crashes on samsung device running operating system version 4.1. While on Marshmallow Nexus 6 device, it works perfectly fine. What is the problem?

Gradle file

```
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.4.0'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.1'
```

I have in my libs folder httpclient-4.3.3.jar
httpclient-cache-4.3.3.jar
httpcore-4.3.2.jar
httpmime-4.3.3.jar

Comment: it works on marshmallow, doesnt on samsung running 4.1. not other way around

Comment: call `compile 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore:4.4.1'
compile 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.5'` this version instead of yours

Comment: @user3278732 Facing same problem ?

Comment: yes, its of no help. the problem is on samsung device with operating system 4.1 , not marshmallow device.

Comment: @user3278732 did you solve yet ?

Comment: it got solved through this compile group: 'org.apache.httpcomponents' , name: 'httpclient-android' , version: '4.3.5.1'
    compile('org.apache.httpcomponents:httpmime:4.3') {
        exclude module: "httpclient"
    }   thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apache http client was removed since marshmallow.

See here [Apache HTTP Client Removal](http://developer.android.com/about/versions/marshmallow/android-6.0-changes.html#behavior-apache-http-client)

Solution (about embed client at all):

```
android {
    useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'
}
```

UPDATED:
About the particular problem see related [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28948599/java-lang-classnotfoundexception-org-apache-http-util-args-which-dependency-s)

Btw, in my project I can't add apache http client as a library, because of package name conflict with embed cliend. I have to use [this](https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-4.3.x/android-port.html) or as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32178854/android-api-23-httpclient-4-x-repackaged)

Comment: the problem is on samsung device with operating system 4.1 , not marshmallow device

Comment: the post was helpful. compile group: 'org.apache.httpcomponents' , name: 'httpclient-android' , version: '4.3.5.1'
    compile('org.apache.httpcomponents:httpmime:4.3') {
        exclude module: "httpclient"
    }  this solved the issue, rather then myself having jar files included in libs folder

Answer (score -1):

For Marshmallow Apache HTTP Client Removal

```
android {
useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'
```

}

try this once

app/build/libs Files >> Project Structure >> Dependencies >> + >> File Dependencies >> and then change it to provided instead of compile (compile will cause a java exit with nonzero value 1 if you are importing too much jars.

Samsung has customised the sdk so there are channces to include more jars..

Comment: it works on marshmallow, doesnt on samsung running 4.1. not other way around

Answer (score -1):

Please include useLibrary url like this

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"
    useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'
```

Comment: the problem is on samsung device with operating system 4.1 , not marshmallow device