# Getting NoSuchMethodError in Low spec devices

Tags: android, android-multidex

I am getting this error on just one particular device which is Moto E Android Version 5.1.1 which is a bit low spec then my production device  Nexus 4 running same 5.1.1, most of the solutions provided here are not working, hope some one can give some pointers.

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No static method notEmpty(Ljava/lang/CharSequence;Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/CharSequence; in class Lorg/apache/http/util/Args; or its super classes (declaration of 'org.apache.http.util.Args' appears in /data/data/com.bowser.cloudthumper/files/instant-run/dex/slice-i2p_9eb30cacd8b3f7a68d7689d883ed4bf9afe9cdd9-classes.dex)
   at org.apache.http.config.RegistryBuilder.register(RegistryBuilder.java:57)
   at org.apache.http.impl.conn.BasicHttpClientConnectionManager.getDefaultRegistry(BasicHttpClientConnectionManager.java:114)
   at org.apache.http.impl.conn.BasicHttpClientConnectionManager.<init>(BasicHttpClientConnectionManager.java:147)
   at org.thoughtcrime.securesms.mms.LegacyMmsConnection.constructHttpClient(LegacyMmsConnection.java:181)
   at org.thoughtcrime.securesms.mms.LegacyMmsConnection.execute(LegacyMmsConnection.java:194)
   at org.thoughtcrime.securesms.mms.OutgoingLegacyMmsConnection.sendBytes(OutgoingLegacyMmsConnection.java:135)
   at org.thoughtcrime.securesms.mms.OutgoingLegacyMmsConnection.send(OutgoingLegacyMmsConnection.java:118)
   at org.thoughtcrime.securesms.mms.OutgoingLegacyMmsConnection.send(OutgoingLegacyMmsConnection.java:93)
   at org.thoughtcrime.securesms.mms.CompatMmsConnection.send(CompatMmsConnection.java:37)
   at org.thoughtcrime.securesms.jobs.MmsSendJob.onSend(MmsSendJob.java:82)
   at org.thoughtcrime.securesms.jobs.SendJob.onRun(SendJob.java:43)
   at org.thoughtcrime.securesms.jobs.MasterSecretJob.onRun(MasterSecretJob.java:18)
   at org.whispersystems.jobqueue.JobConsumer.runJob(JobConsumer.java:76)
   at org.whispersystems.jobqueue.JobConsumer.run(JobConsumer.java:46)
```

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36127232/caused-by-java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-org-apache-http-util-args

Comment: Double check if https://developer.android.com/studio/build/multidex.html is not your case

Comment: @MorrisonChang yes i have gone through that post but it doesn't work in my case, but thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: @R.Zagórski yes i am planning to enable multidex and after that lets see if the error goes away, thanks